# SparkR under RStudio Server on Azure HDInsight

Tags: r, azure, apache-spark, sparkr, rstudio-server

I've installed R 2.3.2, R Studio Server Open, and the SparkR package on an Azure HDInsight cluster (Ubuntu 14.0.4).

I can instantiate SparkR from the R command-line with something like this and it works fine:

```
if (nchar(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME")) < 1) {
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/usr/hdp/2.3.3.1-7/spark")
}

library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local[*]", sparkEnvir = list(spark.driver.memory="2g"))
```

However, the same commands under RStudio Server error out. The [error text is here](http://pastebin.com/56HEtjJ8).   It seems like maybe there are some classpaths that are not being picked up?  Any ideas about how to research/fix this under RStudio Server?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you attach the original error code to your question?

Answer (score 0):

To initiate SparkR on R Server under RStudio it is sufficient to do this:

```
library(SparkR)

sc <- sparkR.init()
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
```